# Provide autocompletion with tree of commands

Tags: python, autocomplete

Here is the sample data structure:

```
commands = {
    'accounts': {},
    'exit': {},
    'login': {},
    'query': {'bank': {}, 'savings': {}},
    'transactions': {'monthly': {}},
    'update': {
        'now': {'please': {}},
        'tomorrow': {'please': {}}
    }
}
```

If we pretend the logic is in **get_choices** I would expect the following output:

```
>> get_choices('upd')
['accounts', 'exit', 'login', 'query', 'transactions', 'update']
>> get_choices('update')
[]
>> get_choices('update ')
['now', 'tomorrow']
>> get_choices('update now ')
['please']
>> get_choices('update now please ')
[]
```

This is my attempt at it, and it works for the above cases, except for the second one, in which case it's returning `['now', 'tomorrow']`.

```
def get_choices(commands, search):
    parts = search.split(' ')
    for part in parts:
        if part in commands:
            return get_choices(commands[part], ' '.join(parts[1:]))
        else:
            return list(commands.keys())

commands = {
    'accounts': {},
    'exit': {},
    'login': {},
    'query': {'bank': {}, 'savings': {}},
    'transactions': {'monthly': {}},
    'update': {
        'now': {'please': {}},
        'tomorrow': {'please': {}}
    }
}

print(get_choices(commands, 'upd'))
print(get_choices(commands, 'update'))
print(get_choices(commands, 'update '))
print(get_choices(commands, 'update now '))
print(get_choices(commands, 'update now please '))
```

Comment: You should really consider your data structure here... In particular, why ever use a `list`? Why not a pure `dict` of `dict`s? Having a list complicates your logic for creating and modifying your `commands` tree, not to mention it complicates what you are trying to accomplish above.

Comment: I looked into using Tries, but I couldn't find any examples that used a complex structure (most were just autocompleting from a simple list of words).

Comment: You can use a trie based on the characters in a word, but you can easily extend that to tokens in a sentence... But regardless, you should still consider the tree you have here. It's not a proper tree, really, it's a dictionary of lists/ or other dictionaries. Essentially, your "nodes" aren't encapsulated types, and are actually differing types based on the nature of the node. This is complicating your logic. Why not dispense with lists and simply use only nested `dict`s?

Comment: Ok, I've updated my post to use dicts, which greatly simplified the logic and allowed me to use recursion. It works for all examples except the second one now, which by the looks of it it's going to be hard to get that specific example to work.

Answer (score 0):

After following Jaunpa's suggestions to change the data structure to be explicitly dictionaries, I was able to greatly compress the logic and get all examples working:

```
def get_choices(commands, search):
    parts = search.split(' ')
    for part in parts:
        if part in commands:
            if len(parts) > 1:
                return get_choices(commands[part], ' '.join(parts[1:]))
            else:
                return []
        else:
            return list(commands.keys())

commands = {
    'accounts': {},
    'exit': {},
    'login': {},
    'query': {'bank': {}, 'savings': {}},
    'transactions': {'monthly': {}},
    'update': {
        'now': {'please': {}},
        'tomorrow': {'please': {}}
    }
}

print(get_choices(commands, 'upd'))
print(get_choices(commands, 'update'))
print(get_choices(commands, 'update '))
print(get_choices(commands, 'update now '))
print(get_choices(commands, 'update now please '))
```